# MQ decoding cuts off dots (...) and changes the message length

Tags: encoding, ibm-mq, message-queue, mq

We are using IBM MQ Series 9 and we are facing a decoding problem.
The messages are being sent from a mainframe with an encoding of 424 (Hebrew) to a Windows-based system. The system pulls the messages out of the queue and parses the messages, and after that, cuts the messages in different parts for advanced parsing.

All messages might include Hebrew characters, hence I am obligated to use Hebrew encoding.

A message in the MQ can look like this:

```
    9921388ABC.........3323DDFF.....43332FFF...2321......
```

After reading the message and parsing it using different code pages the message either doesn't reach the system (using 424, 916) or reaches the system but looks like this:

```
    9921388ABC3323DDFF43332FFF2321
```

The messages are shorter and are unparseable.

I ahve tried to consult with our MQ people but they are clueless about this problem.

Would very appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the rest of those message examples meant to be hex representations of the characters?

Comment: Can you give us a hex example of the message with the MQMD (use amqsbcg sample for example), and tell us what codepage and encoding the MQGET which pulls the message out of the queue uses?

Comment: Hi.
Thank you for your comment, I will fetch it from the systems and will update as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you able to share the windows code that you are using to decode. I would expect the the kind of result you are seeing when using a decoder with an option of ignoring characters it can't recognise. eg. If it's a python app then I would expect to see something like `abc.decode(encoding=xyz, errors='ignore')`